# Update PcManFM-qt in Lubuntu

Tags: pcmanfm-qt

I want update my PCManFM-qt file manager in LXQt desktop from 0.14.2 to 0.17.0 and i use this command:

```
sudo apt install pcmanfm-qt
```

but it says that you are using the latest version.

How can I upgrade PCManFM-qt to the latest version?

Lubuntu: 20.04.3

```
apt policy pcmanfm-qt
```

Output:

```
pcmanfm-qt:
Installed: 0.14.1-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 0.14.1-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 0.14.1-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What version of Lubuntu do You have? I have just checked version of `pcmanfm-qt` in my installation of Ubuntu `21.10` and it's `0.17`.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the output of `apt policy pcmanfm-qt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses the *latest* LTS libraries/toolkot that created at it's creation, which was Qt 5.12 (*5.12.2 or .3 if I recall correctly at release; later updated to 5.12.8 as I recall*) where as later `pcmanfm-qt` requires later toolkits/libraries than are available for 20.04 or *focal*.  FYI:  `pcmanfm-qt` is more than just a file-manager; it handles quite a bit of the LXQt desktop you see, so you need to upgrade your whole desktop; which is currently available given 21.10 is where *do-release-upgrade* will take you.

Answer (score 3):

The updated LXQt will require you to also upgrade your Qt5 version.

Lubuntu 20.04 LTS shipped with the latest version of LXQt that worked with the LTS version of Qt 5.12.8 that was shipped with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Subsequent releases of Qt 5 have not been LTS; so you'll need to upgrade regularly if you do, and by far the easiest fix is to *release-upgrade* to a later release.

fyi:  `pcmanfm-qt` handles much of the LXQt desktop, so you cannot just upgrade that package without upgrading the rest of your LXQt; as well as the Qt toolkit it works with - ie. a large part of your software stack relies on it.

All other Qt5 apps will also need upgrading... (*so they match the newer release you'll have installed*), as all Qt5 apps in a specific release all use the same Qt, which was 5.12.8 LTS for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: If you want to have a look at what's involved; KDE Neon is the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS base; with a Qt5 stack from later Ubuntu releases allowing them to use a later KDE Plasma.  LXQt & KDE share the same Qt5 and the two teams (Kubuntu & Lubuntu) are in touch very regularly as changes impact us both. There are issues with using KDE Neon; and you'll be introducing those same issues into your system -- whether they'll impact you though only you can decide.  If you *nuke & install* to upgrade; you won't care for example.

Comment: When I mentioned Kubuntu & Lubuntu working together, that was for the *focal* or 20.04 cycle.. since that release; Ubuntu Studio is now using Qt5 as their primary desktop toolkit so are involved as well; but they didn't join until *groovy* or after 20.04 as they used Xfce (GTK3) in *focal*

Answer (score 3):

Really you can upgrade `pcmanfm-qt` and other LxQt components to latest versions using [“Lubuntu Continuous Integration” team – UNSTABLE CI Output - Proposed Pocket](https://launchpad.net/%7Elubuntu-ci/+archive/ubuntu/unstable-ci-proposed?field.series_filter=focal)  PPA.
**But be careful as maintainers warn users with "⚠️ This PPA is not meant to be used ⚠️" message.**

Add the above PPA and then install packages from it using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm-qt
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

to get LxQt 0.16 with PcManFm-Qt 0.17:

[image: LxQt from PPA]

To revert to default versions use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed
```

Comment: I update my LXQt but everything went wrong. Please help me to get back to the same stable version.

Comment: Sounds unclear. Use `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed` to revert.

Comment: This just remove unstable ppa and i did it. I want rollback lxqt pcman and all packages to old version

Comment: Then add it back `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed` and then run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed` again. I tried this way on fresh VM before posting. Do not have any issues. This is why I posted it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install lubuntu 21.10 - pcmanfm-qt 0.17 works without issues.
Today it is beta, but will be stable in this month.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+next) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site [expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540)) when your question will be on-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for helping test Lubuntu *impish* though; it's appreciated.    (I'm using it myself; alas it's still off-topic here)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explanation.